# Play .asx links in Metro

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, asx

I'm trying to open some `.asx` links in my Metro App. But `MediaElement` nor `WebView` seems to be working.

any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the playlist (.asx file) contains videos that can be played by Windows 8, I'd recommend downloading the file in your app and parsing it. Then just pass along the actual video urls to the player framework (either by setting the source if there's just one video or by populating the playlist if there are more).